# Сортировка вектора с помощью "sort();"

Tags: c++, qt, сортировка, gui, vector

Пробую реализовать сортировку вектора через sort(), но вылетают следующие ошибки:

> 44: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'sort(QVector::iterator, QVector::iterator, )' sort(Vector.begin(),Vector.end(),cmd);
> d:\qt\tools\mingw48_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:5497: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from '' to 'bool (MainWindow::*)(int, int)'

Вот код:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void Load(); // Загрузить
    void Sort(); // Сортировка
    bool Even_Three(int i); // Чётные и делятся на 3
    bool cmd(int i1,int i2); // Предикат для сортировки
    void Convert(int i, QVector<int>::iterator it); // Преобразовать
    int i;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked(); // Преобразовать

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

QVector<int> Vector;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Vector.clear();
    Load(); // Загрузка
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::Load() { // Загрузить
    QFile file("D:\\Учёба\\2 курс\\4 семестр\\Структуры данных\\Лабы\\File for LR 3.3.1 (C++).txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
    }
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    QTextStream in(&file);
    int n = 0;
    while(!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        Vector.push_back(line.toInt());
        ui->listWidget->addItem(QString::number(Vector[n]));
        n++;
    }
}

void MainWindow::Sort() { // Сортировка
    int n = Vector.count();
    sort(Vector.begin(),Vector.end(),cmd); // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ui->listWidget_2->addItem(QString::number(Vector[i]));
    }
}

bool MainWindow::Even_Three(int i) { // Чётные и делятся на 3
    if (i % 8 == 0) return false;
    else return true;
}

bool MainWindow::cmd(int i1,int i2) // Предикат для сортировки
{ //если i1 надо менять с i2 - вернуть false, иначе true
    if(!Even_Three(i2) && Even_Three(i1))
        return true;

    else
        if(!Even_Three(i2) && !Even_Three(i1) && i1>i2)
            return true;

        else
            if(Even_Three(i2) && Even_Three(i1) &&i2>i1)
                return true;

            else return false;
}

void MainWindow::Convert(int i, QVector<int>::iterator it) { // Преобразовать
    if(i != 0) {
        it = Vector.begin();
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            it++;
        }

        if (!Even_Three(Vector[i]) && Even_Three(Vector[i - 1])) {
            Vector.insert(i-1,Vector[i]);
            Vector.erase(it + 1);
            Convert(i-1, it);
        }

        if (Even_Three(Vector[i]) && Even_Three(Vector[i - 1])) {
            if (Vector[i] < Vector[i - 1]) {
                Vector.insert(i-1,Vector[i]);
                Vector.erase(it + 1);
                Convert(i-1, it);
            }
        }

        if (!Even_Three(Vector[i]) && !Even_Three(Vector[i - 1])) {
            if (Vector[i] > Vector[i - 1]) {
                Vector.insert(i-1,Vector[i]);
                Vector.erase(it + 1);
                Convert(i-1, it);
            }
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() { // Преобразовать
    Convert(i, Vector.begin());
}
```

Условия в коде не те, но взяты из рабочей программы, которую пытаюсь переделать под себя. Интересует, почему ругается сортировка. Уже пробовал делать компаратор статическим, использовать вместо него лямбду, вставлял другие компараторы из примеров в сети, для теста, но ошибка всё та же.

Comment: Что там за cmd? Там должна быть либо функция предикат, либо лямбда. Но не функция-член.

Comment: Это и есть ф-ия предикат, она описана ниже)

Comment: Это функция-член, а не предикат... Прочитайте документацию. Хотите чтобы она была в классе, сделайте ее статической. И вообще, прочитайте пожалуйста саму ошибку.

Comment: private:   static      bool cmd(int i1,int i2); // Предикат для сортировки будет использовать ваш класс и  не является методом объекта

Comment: Я описывал в вопросе, что пытался объявить её статической при помощи static в mainwindow.h и mainwindow.cpp, но это не помогло. Видел примеры, где ф-ию загоняли в структуру, но у меня сходу так не получилось.

Comment: смотрите ответ ниже _  в методе первым аргументом неявно является this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот метод нужно объявить статическим:

```
static bool cmd(int i1,int i2); // Предикат для сортировки
```

А тут передавать указатель:

```
sort(Vector.begin(),Vector.end(),&cmd);
```

Объяснение - нестатические методы класса неявным образом получают указатель на экземпляр класса в первом параметре. Когда вы пытаетесь обратиться к методу cmd напрмую, он хочет три параметра вместо двух, отсюда - ошибка. Ее можно обойти при помощи `bind()` но это не ваш случай

Comment: Сделал, теперь выдаёт:
57: ошибка: 'Even_Three' was not declared in this scope
     if(!Even_Three(i2) && Even_Three(i1))
Нужно как-то играться с параметрами, или объявлением "Even_Three"?

Comment: @BlackDragon статический метод не может вызвать нестатический, так как отсутсвует экземпляр. `Even_Three` также надо сделать статическим.